# TPL ActionBlock not handling messages after an exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I've setup an `ActionBlock<T>` like so:

```
 private readonly ActionBlock<PresentationListNotification> _actionBlock;
    
    ...
    
  _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<PresentationListNotification>(HandleNotification);
```

Each time i wish to invoke the actionblock i do so like this:

```
try
{
    _actionBlock.Post(notification);
}
catch (AggregateException aggException)
{
    foreach (Exception ex in aggException.InnerExceptions)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex,"Exception {Message} occurred processing notification", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but I've noticed that when an exception occurred in the `HandleNotification` delegate (the actual implementation isn't probably important but it occurred when I was trying the set the result on a `TaskCompletionSource` which was in a faulted state), the actionblock would fail to post subsequent messages to my handler. In the debugger I could see that the `IsCompleted` and `IsDecliningPermanently` properties were True. How do I recover when the actionblock is in this state?

Comment: That's by design and actually expected. Don't let exceptions escape the worker function. The block itself can't know how serious an exception was so the only logical thing is to assume it can't proceed with its work any more and finish in a faulted state. If a block, eg a TransformBlock is linked to other blocks with `PropagateCompletion=True` the faulted state will be passed to all downstream blocks

Comment: BTW the catch block here won't do anything. `Post` doesn't throw even if the buffer is full. The exceptions thrown by Dataflow blocks are not propagated upstream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I recover when the actionblock is in this state?

You can't. When a dataflow block has faulted, it will remain in this state forever. There is no recovering after that. You could consider:

1. Prevent the block from failing, by `try`-`catch`ing any exception thrown inside the `action`.
2. After the failure, replace the faulted block with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As a fan of TPL Dataflow, I've settled on the following design pattern, unless you are satisfied with the default behavior that the entire block stops processing messages when an unhandled exception occurs.

- Handle all exceptions in the delegate with which the block is created.
- Wrap your input and/or output in a state object that conveys not only the actual input message and/or output message but if the operation was successful and captures the exception message if not (much like `Task<T>` captures the result or an exception).

Either:

a) Each block in the pipeline checks if the previous operation was successful or not and either passes on the error or continues with it's happy path operation.

b) Or each block uses the propagation extensions to connect to the next, with a filter clause that sends failed messages to a standalone queue or block for error handling/logging.

If 'a', then at the end of the pipeline, have a propagation clause with a filter that passes the final state object to an error block or success block, and does whatever final step is necessary.

Don't forget to send a completion signal to any standalone blocks when your primary pipeline is complete.